# How to search for only folders in Windows 7 instead of folders AND files

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-search

I've had some issues with the new search function in Windows 7. The Search in Windows XP was packed with so many more options. The only option I can access now are *Date Modified* and *Size.*

Any pointers to how to get more options in the Windows 7 Search, or links to external programs that can make my life easier?

Comment: Related: [How can I see the available Windows Search Filters?](http://superuser.com/q/531659/354511)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

From the [**Windows Search Advanced Query Syntax**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711(v=vs.85).aspx) page, use the following search items:

```
To restrict by file type    Use            Example
------------------------    ---            -------
Folders                     folders        kind:folders
Folder name                 foldername     foldername:mydocs
```

Comment: Now I see, maybe the Windows 7 search is a bit better suited for search than the Windows XP version =)

Comment: @sshow - you should say thanks to snark by up voting the answer.
+1 from me

Comment: Just great, Thanks a lot. I was looking for that for a while ;)

Comment: `foldername` is not correct. It searches for files and folders inside of folders of a certain name.

Comment: `kind:folders` (or `kind:folder`) finds folders, but also collection files like `*.CAB` and `*.ZIP`.  To find only true folders, use `type:folder`.

Comment: +1
In Windows 10 Pro: `kind:folder myfolder`

Comment: BTW this works only for the **English versions of Windows**, for other languages you need to use the translated key word (whatever it may be), yeah, it sucks.

Comment: To know what "folder" is called in your language, simply go to a folder and check the properties of it, there it should say "Type: Folder" as the first attribute of the first tab in your language. That is the word you should use for your language, and hopefully what is translated as "Type:" is what you should use before the colon.

Comment: How can I find only empty folders ? And/Or folders whose size is less than 100 or 10 KB ?

Answer (score 34):

In the *Search* box type:

```
type:="File Folder" name:[enter the folder name here with no brackets]
```

Comment: this is the best answer. you can also put *, e.g. name:*middle*

Comment: `type:"File Folder"` (without the equals sign) works as well.

Comment: How can I find only empty folders ? And/Or folders whose size is less than 100 or 10 KB ?

Comment: `type:="file folder"` (lower case `f`) works as well

Answer (score 16):

I understand that you are asking specifically for windows-search based answers, but here is an alternate method in case it is helpful.

Open up the windows command prompt and navigate to the directory from which you want to start searching and use the following command:

```
dir *SEARCH_TERM* /ad /s
```

Windows Search just makes me howl with rage for a few minutes before I give up and just do the same search from the command prompt instead.

Comment: Very fast and good solution. :) But I prefer to add */b* for single line output. ;)

Answer (score 5):

On a **german** version of Windows 7 you'll need the filter below, because *type:folder* or the like won't work at all:

```
typ:=Dateiordner
```

BTW, if you press **Win+F**, the searchbox will offer at least a tiny bit of assistance below the box and clicking on its blue links will trigger selection widgets.

Answer (score 2):

Tired of Windows 7 search wonders I use FileSeek [http://www.fileseek.ca](http://www.fileseek.ca/)
It has lots of options: date/size filters, regular expressions, inclusive/exclusive search, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In `cmd.exe` CLI, go to the folder you want to search from, then `dir /ad /b /s "search-string"`

Please note that it must be `cmd.exe`, as I found it is an issue when using `PowerShell` with that command

Answer (score 1):

This answer is posted as an answer to a question that was closed as a duplicate,  [Windows Explorer Search for: Folder name BEGINS WITH [Search term]](https://superuser.com/questions/1725175/windows-explorer-search-for-folder-name-begins-with-search-term), despite the fact that the accepted answer to this question is wrong because the `FolderName` property of a folder is its parent:

- Test folders:

  [image]
- `FolderName:FindMe` search results:

  [image]

The second answer is closer, but *doesn't* limit results to names that begin with the desired search term:

- `type:="File Folder" name:FIndMe` search results:

  [image]

To limit results to those names that *begin* with the desired search string, you have to use the relatively unknown query operator `~<`, documented [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-advancedquerysyntax#query-operators) :

- `type:Directory name:~<FindMe` serach results:

  [image]

  - Note: `type:Directory` == `type:"File Folder"`

Another useful operator documented on the linked page is `~` (Allow DOS wildcards within quoted strings):

- `type:Directory name:~"FindMe*"` serach results:

  [image]

It's useful when you search term contains special characters like parentheses:

- `type:Directory name:~"*(desired)*"` search results:

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a French Windows 7 none of the above phrases works. You need a plus sign between the key words (+)

type:="Dossier de fichiers" + nom: [input the folder name, without the brackets. Add a space after : character]

Example:
type:="Dossier de fichiers" + nom: Bozo Abc

Comment: (1) I appreciate the fact that the French version of Microsoft Windows requires certain commands and keywords to be entered in French.  But please write the narrative / descriptive part of your answer in English.  The user isn’t actually supposed to ***type*** “tapez le nom de votre dossier, sans les parenthèses. Tapez un espace après nom”, are they?  (2) If you are copying this answer from somewhere, you should say where.