# folder only search with Windows Search in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, windows-search

I am trying to find all the sub-folders called **2013** in in a network directory using the Explorer Search box in Windows Explorer on Server 2008.

I have tried options like *kinde:folders foldername:2012*

but get no results.

I know that there are hundreds of sub-folders in about 120 folders like this:

\ISA Renewal Confirmation_archive\2012

I would like to find all the folders with **2012** so we can move them all in one step to a backup drive.

I looked at this [SuperUser.com: how-to-search-for-folders-only-in-windows-7-instead-of-folders-and-files](https://superuser.com/questions/116514/how-to-search-for-folders-only-in-windows-7-instead-of-folders-and-files) and tried some options but no luck.

What am I doing wrong please?

thanks

Comment: Non-English language or type-o? If not, then "kinde:" should be "kind:".

Comment: Have you ensured the "System" account has access to those folders (that what the search service runs as)?  Have you ensured they are being indexed?

Comment: @TECHIE007: good point, they may not be indexed - I guess we'll have to manage with an alternative option like building a batch file or vba tool to list the folders and move them to a place where they will be off the network file server and on backup...