# How to search for directories only in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-search

For example searching for file does right thing: 
file:.git 
However searching for directory returns nothing: 
directory:.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `folder:` instead.

For example `folder: .git` will search for all directories that have .git in them.

It will still find files inside them.

If you really want folders only, use kind:folders ".git"

Notice how folder: gets blue, indicating that it's a filter that will work.

This is tested to work in Windows 10. Given that you did not mention what OS you are using, I will assume you use the latest at this time of writing, which is Windows 10, but it probably works in earlier versions too.

Comment: folder: .git doesn't work despite i see .git directories (folder: ".git" either)

Comment: kind:folders ".git" works - from https://superuser.com/questions/116514/how-to-search-for-only-folders-in-windows-7-instead-of-folders-and-files

Comment: Edited the answer. Thanks for the feedback. Feel free to mark the answer as answered, so others know you no longer need help.