# Windows Explorer Search for: Folder name BEGINS WITH [Search term]

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-search

How can you find folders in Windows Explorer whose name **STARTS WITH** the exact search term, **WITHOUT** at the same time finding folders that **CONTAIN** the search term somewhere in the name?

Of course, this is quite easy with third-party software such as Voidtools Everything, however in this case it must be done specifically with Windows Explorer.

**This is not a duplicate of [How to search for only folders in Windows 7 instead of folders AND files](https://superuser.com/questions/116514/how-to-search-for-only-folders-in-windows-7-instead-of-folders-and-files) because the present question is not even touched over there AT ALL. Please remove the duplicate mark.**

Comment: `foldername:myText*` or just `name:myText*`  might be a good start

Comment: @David.P what have you tried?

Comment: The good 'ol command prompt helps here too.  `dir /ad /s "yourSearchTerm*"`

Comment: `dir /a /s /b | find /i "\starts-with"`, I have not found ANY File explorer Search "manual" and neither been able to make it work in a sane manner. Many times MISSING obvious hits **in the folder I'm launching it in**.

Comment: @Mokubai - do you by any chance have a pointer to an actual DOCUMENT telling about "foldername:" being a valid entry in the search field?

Comment: @Hannu yes. In the accepted answer on the duplicate I found.

Comment: The marked duplicate CONTAINS the answer to your question. Yours is a duplicate.

Comment: @Hannu: The most obvious "documentation" for `FolderName` is the fact that "Folder name" is an available column when **EXplorer** is displaying a folder in `Details` mode. However, it's not what you need. If you add the column, you'll see that it displays the *parent* folder of folders  listed in the `Details` view.

Comment: As an alternative to wildcard syntax, there are some lesser-known [query operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-advancedquerysyntax#query-operators): `~<` specifies `Starts with` and `~>` specifies `Ends with`. To limit results to actual directories and exclude `.zip` folders, use `System.IsFolder:True`. So you could use: `name:~<SearchText System.IsFolder:True`.

Comment: Also: While `type:folder` still returns `.zip` files as well as folders, `type:directory` limits results to actual file system folders, so it's a viable alternative to `System.IsFolder:True`

Comment: Keith, this information totally rocks! Would you be so kind as to write this up as an answer to the original question? 

Is this really not documented anywhere else by Microsoft, especially for regular Windows Explorer users and not just for programmers?

Comment: @David.P: I posted the answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1725923/881098).

Comment: Awesome, thank you Keith